# Inject Angular Service to Utils Class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

I want to use the these following services and pipes in my utility class of my Angular project: 'calculateImgtimeService', 'hoursWonSumPipe', 'checkObjectEmptyPipe'. I am not able to inject it or make it available to the Utils Class. I have tried several different ways to instantiate the Services, but it didn't work. Maybe someone of you knows how to do it. When i try to call some method from the 'calculateImgtimeService' i get the message "Error Message: Property 'calculateImgtimeService' does not exist on type 'typeof Utils'" - Thats probably because i didn't inject the service correctly.. What would be the right way to solve my problem?

**The Utility Class:**

```
import { CalculateImgtimeService } from './services/calculate-imgtime.service';
import { HoursWonSumPipe } from './pipes/hours-won-sum.pipe';
import { CheckObjectEmptyPipe } from './pipes/check-object-empty.pipe';

export default class Utils {

  constructor(
    private calculateImgtimeService: CalculateImgtimeService, 
    private hoursWonSumPipe: HoursWonSumPipe,
    private checkObjectEmptyPipe: CheckObjectEmptyPipe) {
  }

  static myUtilsMethod() {
    this.calculateImgtimeService.someMethod(); <-- "Error Message: Property 'calculateImgtimeService' does not exist on type 'typeof Utils'"
  }

}
```

**The 'calculateImgtimeService':**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Utils from '../utils';
declare var SunCalc: any; // https://github.com/mourner/suncalc

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalculateImgtimeService {

  enebaleLogging = false; // Set this to true if you want to see debug logging

  constructor() { }

  someMethod() {
    some code here...
  }
}
```

**The App Module:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { dateFormatPipe } from './pipes/format-date.pipe';
import { timeFormatPipe } from './pipes/format-time.pipe';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CalendarComponent } from './components/calendar/calendar.component';

import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { CheckObjectEmptyPipe } from './pipes/check-object-empty.pipe';
import { HoursWonSumPipe } from './pipes/hours-won-sum.pipe';
import { MatDatepickerModule, NativeDateModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { IsDateTodayPipe } from './pipes/is-date-today.pipe';
import { CalendarDetailComponent } from './components/calendar-detail/calendar-detail.component';
import { FilterComponent } from './components/filter/filter.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    dateFormatPipe,
    timeFormatPipe,
    CalendarComponent,
    CheckObjectEmptyPipe,
    HoursWonSumPipe,
    IsDateTodayPipe,
    CalendarDetailComponent,
    FilterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    NativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule
  ],
  providers: [
    dateFormatPipe,
    timeFormatPipe,
    HoursWonSumPipe,
    CheckObjectEmptyPipe
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: For one thing that's a static method, which doesn't get access to instance properties.

Comment: Why is Utils class not a service? By making it service angular will handle the DI for you. I don’t see why you wouldn’t want this to be a service.

Comment: @bjlasc01 yes, thats true didn't came up in my mind at first - thanks

Comment: @RiccoSkombar were you able to solve the problem ?